# Query users & roles (ASP.NET identity) via Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-identity

I want to get patients and doctors from database. I am using ASP.NET Identity.

The relevant tables are `AspNetUsers`, `AspNetRoles`and `AspNetUserRoles`

And this is my query:

```
var result = from pateints in context.Users
             let pEmail = pateints.Email
             from doctors in context.Users
             from roles in context.Roles
             where pateints.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roles.Id && roles.Name == "Patient")
             where doctors.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == roles.Id && roles.Name == "Doctor") 
             select new { doctors.Email, pEmail };
```

I tried my best to find the problem, but this query returns nothing.

Comment: Try using Lambda instead of Linq Expressions. Lambda is easy to read and debug. I really hate Linq Expressions.

Comment: Include your tables please.

Comment: These are the tables defined by the Identity @Llazar

Comment: Thanks but I haven't used Lambda before. @IgorQuirino

Comment: `pateints` are in `context.Users` or in `context.Roles`?

Comment: `ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();` is the connection. By using this connection I am accessing the tables.
`context.Users = AspNetUsers` and `context.Roles = AspNetRoles`

Comment: and `AspNetUserRoles` contains the `roleId` and `UserId` fields.

Comment: You are not clear with your question and there is not enough info to help you. You want to retrieve patients and doctors from database right, what are they in your database?

Comment: @Llazar let me try to explain for you. 
All users are in the table `AspNetUsers` fields `userid`,`Username` etc but their roles are in the table `AspNetRoles` fields `roleId`, 'Name' and each user is assigned a role which may be a doctor, patient or other and their relationship table is `AspNetUserRoles` which contains the `userId` and `roleId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to join all three entities and then apply filter on role name like below -

```
var result = from u in context.Users
             join ur context.UserRoles on u.Userid equal ur.Userid
             join r in context.Roles on r.Roleid equal ur.Roleid
             where r.Name == "Doctor" || r.Name == "Patient"
             select new {UserName = u.UserName, Email = u.Email, Role = r.Name };
```

The sample output will be like below -

```
UserName        Email           Role
abc xyz         abc@abc.com     Doctor
doc xyz         doc@abc.com     Doctor
pqr xyz         pqr@abc.com     Patient
lmn xyz         lmn@abc.com     Patient
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    using(ApplicationDbContext db=new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
          var users = (from user in db.Users
                       from roles in user.Roles
                       join role in db.Roles
                       on roles.RoleId equals role.Id 
                       select new
                       {
                           user.UserName, 
                           role.Name
                       }).ToList(); 
    }
```